# Exception when deploying a UWP Windows app in master mode

Tags: c#

Attempting to deploy a UWP Windows app in master mode throws an unhandled exception as follows:

> Unhandled exception at 0x603FF073 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in
>   HopTheBall.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has
>   occurred (parameters: 0x038C1FB0, 0x00000002).

[image]

Can anyone give the rectification for this error?

Comment: Did you tried to check the output window for more information?

Comment: There is only Debug and Release Mode in general UWP project when building. So does it mean that you are trying to build a project which is compiled from Unity?

Comment: Hello Koby,
Thanks for your response.You are right, I am trying on Unity Game project for UWP. Since I  am able to generate build on Unity 3D engine, I am facing issues while 'Master' Debugging on Visual Studio. I wonder build is running on modes respectively.

Thanks once again.

Regards,

AkhilBhaskar

Comment: Can Anyone Give The Urgent Rectification For That